# Multiple url fetches Google App Engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am creating an application on GAE that at a point needs to fetch data from remote servers using GET methods. Doing so in a sequential manner is rather slow; first make the request, get a response, process it and then to the next request etc. Is it possible to do all this in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do async calls using
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests